# Add class for the column in the html table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

Please tell me how to add my class for the column in the table (all the cells of the selected column) using jQuery?

For example, I need a column №2

```
<table id = 'mytable'>
<tbody>
<tr><td></td>...<td></td></tr>
...
<tr><td></td>...<td></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

$('#mytable td.eq( 1 )').addClass('myclass'); // set class for only one cell :(
```

I want

```
<table id = 'mytable'>
<tbody>
<tr><td></td><td class = 'myclass'></td>...<td></td></tr>
...
<tr><td></td><td class = 'myclass'></td>...<td></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use CSS [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector to add rules, no need use [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)

```css
#mytable td:nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table id='mytable'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [:nth-child()](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector:

```
 $('#mytable tr td:nth-child(2)').addClass('myClass');
```

The `nth-child` will allow you to select the desired column by specifying the column number. Also, you need to include `JQuery` plugin in your HTML file.

```js
 $('#mytable tr td:nth-child(2)').addClass('myClass');
```

```css
td:nth-child(2) {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do with [`each()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjG27CgzovWAhXCOY8KHavzAXsQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Feach%2F&usg=AFQjCNERiS3iAZ_VNLBSp22Y5a_-bQPP3w) function. And change the [`:eq(1)`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjqzYqVzovWAhWCrI8KHZLmB3YQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Feq%2F&usg=AFQjCNF421AWRe2A4OnKM21N9XQV5cUFMA) instead of `.eq(1)`.its a wrong jquery object

```
$('#mytable tbody tr').each(function(){
$(this).find('td:eq(1)').addClass('myclass');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#mytable td:nth-of-type(2)').addClass('myclass');
```

```css
.myclass {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table id='mytable'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>first</td>
      <td>second</td>
      <td>thirth</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>first</td>
      <td>second</td>
      <td>thirth</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this using Jquery... It will work for your code... which selects element td which comes after another td...

```
$('#mytable tr td~td').addClass('myClass');
```

for specific selection... use nth child...

```
$('#mytable tr td:nth-child(2)').addClass('myClass');
```